# Resume python code without exiting subprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, os.system

I have a main python script which calls several subscripts --> `main.py`
My first sub script `subscript1.py` runs a few lines of code then at the end, opens an external program (putty) using `subprocess`. The program to be opened is a data monitor which I want to keep open the whole time.
I want to return to `main.py` so that `subscript2.py` can be run.

**Problem: python code doesn't resume until external program from subprocess is closed. How can I keep subprocess open but carry on with my python code?**

main.py:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['python', 'subscript1.py'])

subprocess.call(['python', 'subscript2.py'])
```

subscript1.py:

```
import subprocess

prog_path = 'C:/Programs/PUTTY.exe'
load_config = 'config_to_load'

... lines of code to check for a condition 

if outcome_value == 1:
    subprocess.run(prog_path, 'load', load_config)
else:
    print("error message")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I will use `multiprocessing.pool`

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import subprocess

def do_wait(_):
    subprocess.call(['python','-c',"import time;time.sleep(1)"])

st = time.time()
with Pool(5) as p:
    print(p.map(do_wait, [1, 2, 3]))
diff = time.time() - st
print(f"total : {diff} sec")
```

Comment: I just show you an implementation example. You can apply the idea to your code creatively.